How to Return a Strongly-Typed Class with Deep Traversal When Querying Data from Gremlin Using Gremlin.NET
I’m working on querying data from Gremlin. After a few days of effort, I can now query the data and return the expected output format using ToDynamic. However, I need to return a strongly-typed class to keep the code clean. When using a strongly-typed class, though, I cannot access the outE to get the inV for further queries.
Here is the code that produces the desired output:
            IVertexGremlinQuery<Conversation> conversationQuery = gremlinQuerySource
                .V<Account>()
                .Where(account => account.Id == accountId)
                .OutE<Has>()
                .InV<Conversation>();

            long count = await conversationQuery.Count().FirstAsync();

            var paginatedConversations = conversationQuery
                .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                .Limit(pageSize);

            var conversationWithMessages = paginatedConversations
                .Project(p => p.ToDynamic()
                .By(conversation => conversation.Id)
                .By(conversation => conversation.Title)
                .By(conversation => conversation.IsDirectMessage)
                .By("Participants", conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>()
                    .Project(account => account.ToDynamic()
                    .By(account => account.Id)
                    .By(account => account.Email)
                    .By(account => account.FullName)
                    .By(account => account.Gender)
                ).Fold())
                .By("Messages", p => p.OutE<Has>().InV<ConversationMessage>()
                    .Project(p => p.ToDynamic()
                    .By(p => p.Id)
                    .By(p => p.Content)
                    .By(p => p.SenderId)
                    .By(p => p.Timestamp)
                    ).Fold())
                );
            var source = await conversationWithMessages.ToArrayAsync();
            return source;


And it produces the following output:
[
  {
    "Id": "58d7f798-ec17-48ff-a0b4-61d2e429d4e0",
    "Title": "",
    "IsDirectMessage": true,
    "Participants": [
      {
        "Id": "46c8bdb6-be60-4eb1-b03f-96be2ebb4f00",
        "Email": "vannongtinh@gmail.com",
        "FullName": "",
        "Gender": "0"
      },
      {
        "Id": "c4085232-15e4-4555-864a-a441a546d098",
        "Email": "vannongtinh1@gmail.com",
        "FullName": "",
        "Gender": "0"
      }
    ],
    "Messages": [
      {
        "Id": "83ecd9e7-6820-4b0f-a0ef-89cf0c4d55e1",
        "Content": "helllllllllllllllllllllo",
        "SenderId": "46c8bdb6-be60-4eb1-b03f-96be2ebb4f00",
        "Timestamp": "1726437703827"
      },
      {
        "Id": "e71e7269-2ec7-4579-a0bb-289a904c627b",
        "Content": "jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj",
        "SenderId": "46c8bdb6-be60-4eb1-b03f-96be2ebb4f00",
        "Timestamp": "1726437799277"
      }
    ]
  }
]

But when I changed the query to use a strongly-typed class, I lost access to the outE method.
            IVertexGremlinQuery<ConversationDto> conversationWithMessages = paginatedConversations
                .Project(p => p.To<ConversationDto>()
                .By(conversation => conversation.Id, c => c.Values(a => a.Id))
                .By(conversation => conversation.Title, c => c.Values(a => a.Title))
                .By(conversation => conversation.IsDirectMessage, c => c.Values(a => a.IsDirectMessage))
                // CS1061  'ConversationDto' does not contain a definition for 'OutE' and no accessible extension method 'OutE' accepting a first argument of type 'ConversationDto' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)
                .By(conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>()
                    .Project(account => account.To<AccountDto>()
                    .By(account => account.Id, a => a.Values(a => a.Id))
                    .By(account => account.Email, a => a.Values(a => a.Email))
                    .By(account => account.FullName, a => a.Values(a => a.FullName))
                    .By(account => account.Gender, a => a.Values(a => a.Gender))
                    ).Fold(), (c, participants) => c.Participants = participants)
                // CS1061  'ConversationDto' does not contain a definition for 'OutE' and no accessible extension method 'OutE' accepting a first argument of type 'ConversationDto' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)
                .By(conversation => conversation.OutE<Has>().InV<ConversationMessage>()
                    .Project(message => message.To<ConversationMessageDto>()
                    .By(message => message.Id, m => m.Values(m => m.Id))
                    .By(message => message.Content, m => m.Values(m => m.Content))
                    .By(message => message.SenderId, m => m.Values(m => m.SenderId))
                    .By(message => message.Timestamp, m => m.Values(m => m.Timestamp))
                    ).Fold(), (c, messages) => c.Messages = messages)
                );

There is no documentation on this issue, so I’m not sure where to look. However, this seems like the perfect place to find an expert to help with this problem.

I still cannot return a strongly-typed class when querying data from different vertices. However, after I retrieve the data, I know that it matches the format of my target class. Therefore, I serialize the data into a string and then deserialize it to obtain the object I want, using Newtonsoft.Json since System.Text.Json doesn't work well in my case. Here is the full code:

        public async Task<ApiResult<ConversationDto>> GetInboxAsync(string accountId, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            IVertexGremlinQuery<Conversation> conversationQuery = gremlinQuerySource
                .V<Account>()
                .Where(account => account.Id == accountId)
                .OutE<Has>()
                .InV<Conversation>();

            long count = await conversationQuery.Count().FirstAsync();

            IVertexGremlinQuery<Conversation> paginatedConversations = conversationQuery
                .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                .Limit(pageSize);

            IGremlinQuery<dynamic> conversationWithMessages = paginatedConversations
                .Project(p => p.ToDynamic()
                .By(conversation => conversation.Id)
                .By(conversation => conversation.Title)
                .By(conversation => conversation.IsDirectMessage)
                .By("Participants", conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>()
                    .Project(account => account.ToDynamic()
                    .By(account => account.Id)
                    .By(account => account.Email)
                    .By(account => account.FullName)
                    .By(account => account.Gender)
                ).Fold())
                .By("Messages", p => p.OutE<Has>().InV<ConversationMessage>()
                    .Project(p => p.ToDynamic()
                    .By(p => p.Id)
                    .By(p => p.Content)
                    .By(p => p.SenderId)
                    .By("Sender", p => p.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>()
                        .Project(account => account.ToDynamic()
                        .By(account => account.Id)
                        .By(account => account.Email)
                        .By(account => account.FullName)
                        .By(account => account.Gender)
                    ))
                    .By(p => p.Timestamp)
                    ).Fold())
                );

            dynamic[] source = await conversationWithMessages.ToArrayAsync();
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);

            ConversationDto[] conversations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationDto[]>(jsonString)!;

            ApiResult<ConversationDto> apiResult = ApiResult<ConversationDto>.CreateAsync(
                conversations,
                count,
                pageIndex,
                pageSize
            );

            return apiResult;
        }

